# Where are AzureKeyVaultSecret backup/import powershell commands?

Tags: powershell, azure, scripting, azure-keyvault

I need to export all secrets from my key vault in Azure but I get the following error:

> Backup-AzureKeyVaultSecret : The term 'Backup-AzureKeyVaultSecret' is
>   not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
>   operable program.

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/?view=azurermps-4.4.1) the command is in AzureRM.KeyVault module but it isn't on my machine:

```
> PS C:\> get-module AzureRM
> 
> ModuleType Version    Name                               
> ExportedCommands
> ---------------- Script     4.4.1      AzureRM                             {Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount, Add-AzureKeyVaultCertif...
> 
> 
>PS C:\> Get-Command -Module AzureRM.KeyVault -Noun azurekeyvault*|Select-Object Name, Version

Name                                             Version
----                                             -------
Set-AzureKeyVaultKey                             3.4.1
Add-AzureKeyVaultCertificate                     2.8.0
Add-AzureKeyVaultCertificateContact              2.8.0
Add-AzureKeyVaultKey                             2.8.0
Backup-AzureKeyVaultKey                          2.8.0
Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate                     2.8.0
Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificateContact              2.8.0
Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificateIssuer               2.8.0
Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificateOperation            2.8.0
Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificatePolicy               2.8.0
Get-AzureKeyVaultKey                             2.8.0
Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret                          2.8.0
Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate                  2.8.0
New-AzureKeyVaultCertificateAdministratorDetails 2.8.0
New-AzureKeyVaultCertificateOrganizationDetails  2.8.0
New-AzureKeyVaultCertificatePolicy               2.8.0
Remove-AzureKeyVaultCertificate                  2.8.0
Remove-AzureKeyVaultCertificateContact           2.8.0
Remove-AzureKeyVaultCertificateIssuer            2.8.0
Remove-AzureKeyVaultCertificateOperation         2.8.0
Remove-AzureKeyVaultKey                          2.8.0
Remove-AzureKeyVaultSecret                       2.8.0
Restore-AzureKeyVaultKey                         2.8.0
Set-AzureKeyVaultCertificateAttribute            2.8.0
Set-AzureKeyVaultCertificateIssuer               2.8.0
Set-AzureKeyVaultCertificatePolicy               2.8.0
Set-AzureKeyVaultKeyAttribute                    2.8.0
Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret                          2.8.0
Set-AzureKeyVaultSecretAttribute                 2.8.0
Stop-AzureKeyVaultCertificateOperation           2.8.0
```

Note, `Backup-AzureKeyVaultKey` is present but there is no `Backup-AzureKeyVaultSecret`. I tried `Update-Module AzureRM` but there are no new commands. Where is this thing?

Comment: what makes you think there is such a cmdlet?

Comment: The official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/Backup-AzureKeyVaultSecret?view=azurermps-4.4.1

Comment: in that case: reboot,delete all azurerm folders from the pc, launch powershell and install them from scratch

Comment: @UserControl Could you use `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh` to get your Azure Power Shell version?

Comment: @UserControl I test 4.4.1. The cmdlet works for me. You could download it from the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/tag/v4.4.1-October2017).

Answer (score 3):

The recommendation is to download and install the latest Azure Powershell MSI-installer through GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases

Currently the latest version is available though the following direct link: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/download/v4.4.1-October2017/azure-powershell.4.4.1.msi

I've run into the same issue and installing the MSI helped to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I had to do

```
Uninstall-Module AzureRm.KeyVault
```

twice (??), and then

```
Install-Module AzureRm.KeyVault  -Force -AllowClobber
```

It didn't work without both `-Force` and `-AllowClobber` flags. Something with parallel version installation thing.